# JQuery script works in JSFiddle, but doesn't in my own browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

As the title says...
Tried changing the JQuery vesion. Tried different browsers (Mozilla, Chrome, Opera, IE). Also tried loading the JQuery library from my own server. Haven't had any luck. Help me out, please.

Here, the code works in JSFiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/GUuNG/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.1/summoner/by-name/krepo?api_key=b05c2251-f659-4d24-8b5f-6b25a482b42a"  , function(result){
            $.each(result, function(key, value){
            $("div").append("<b>" +key+"--"+value +"</b><br/>");
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Get Json Data</button>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check your browser console.. is there any error

Comment: the problem is definatly at jsfiddle

Comment: Your jsfiddle is different than the code you have above...

Comment: Well, I get these errors upon loading the page, but when I click the button, nothing shows up in the console.

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=viktczu&userId=7e820d0d208d4f2c98e7ea1f281b34e5&CTID=CDCTzbutbR".

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=viktczu&userId=7e820d0d-208d-4f2c-98e7-ea1f281b34e5&CTID=7e820d0d208d4f2c98e7ea1f281b34e5".

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have the `src` and body for a script element

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.1/summoner/by-name/krepo?api_key=b05c2251-f659-4d24-8b5f-6b25a482b42a"  , function(result){
            $.each(result, function(key, value){
            $("div").append("<b>" +key+"--"+value +"</b><br/>");
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

[HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)

> The script may be defined within the contents of the SCRIPT element or
>   in an external file. If the src attribute is not set, user agents must
>   interpret the contents of the element as the script. If the src has a
>   URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve
>   the script via the URI. Note that the charset attribute refers to the
>   character encoding of the script designated by the src attribute; it
>   does not concern the content of the SCRIPT element.

Comment: I would guess this is the answer.